# HowTo get the class of _ :Any

Tags: class, scala, types, scala-2.8, type-systems

I've wrapped a Message and would like to log which message I've wrapped.

```
val any :Any = msg.wrappedMsg
var result :Class[_] = null
```

The only solution I could find is matching everything:

```
result = any match {
  case x:AnyRef => x.getClass
  case _:Double => classOf[Double]
  case _:Float  => classOf[Float]
  case _:Long   => classOf[Long]
  case _:Int    => classOf[Int]
  case _:Short  => classOf[Short]
  case _:Byte   => classOf[Byte]
  case _:Unit   => classOf[Unit]
  case _:Boolean=> classOf[Boolean]
  case _:Char   => classOf[Char]
}
```

I wonder if there's a better solution?
The following 2 approaches do not work :(

```
result = any.getClass //error
// type mismatch;  found   : Any  required: ?{val getClass: ?} 
// Note: Any is not implicitly converted to AnyRef.  
// You can safely pattern match x: AnyRef or cast x.asInstanceOf[AnyRef] to do so.
result = any match {
  case x:AnyRef => x.getClass
  case x:AnyVal => /*voodoo to get class*/ null // error
}
//type AnyVal cannot be used in a type pattern or isInstanceOf
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can safely call `.asInstanceOf[AnyRef]` on any Scala value, which will box primitives:

```
scala> val as = Seq("a", 1, 1.5, (), false)
as: Seq[Any] = List(, 1, 1.5, (), false)

scala> as map (_.asInstanceOf[AnyRef])
res4: Seq[AnyRef] = List(a, 1, 1.5, (), false)
```

From there, you can call `getClass`.

```
scala> as map (_.asInstanceOf[AnyRef].getClass)
res5: Seq[java.lang.Class[_]] = List(class java.lang.String, class java.lang.Int
eger, class java.lang.Double, class scala.runtime.BoxedUnit, class java.lang.Boo
lean)
```

Tested with 2.8.0.RC6, I don't know it this worked in 2.7.7.

Definitely new in 2.8 are the companion objects for the classes derived from AnyVal. They contain handy `box` and `unbox` methods:

```
scala> Int.box(1)
res6: java.lang.Integer = 1

scala> Int.unbox(res6)
res7: Int = 1
```

Answer (score 3):

Won't casting just do the trick, as suggested in the error message?

```
scala> val d:Double = 0.0
d: Double = 0.0

scala> d.asInstanceOf[AnyRef].getClass
res0: java.lang.Class[_] = class java.lang.Double
```

Answer (score 3):

As of scala 2.10.0, `getClass` is available on `Any` (and not just on `AnyRef`), so you don't  need to do any contorsion anymore and can just do `any.getClass`.

Note though that you still must be prepared to handlet the dual relation between primitive types and their boxed version. 
By example `getClass` on an integer value will return either `java.lang.Integer.TYPE` (the class of the primitive `Int` type) or `classOf[java.lang.Integer]` depending on the static type of the value:

```
scala> 123.getClass
res1: Class[Int] = int

scala> val x : Int = 123
x: Int = 123

scala> x.getClass
res2: Class[Int] = int

scala> val x: AnyVal = 123
x: AnyVal = 123

scala> x.getClass
res3: Class[_] = class java.lang.Integer

scala> val x: Any = 123
x: Any = 123

scala> x.getClass
res4: Class[_] = class java.lang.Integer
```