# Compile error in scala, why: val num =123;println(num.getClass())

Tags: scala

I'm new to scala. I tried this code:

```
val name = "mike"
println(name.getClass())
```

It's OK and printed `java.lang.String`

But, when I try:

```
val num = 123
println(num.getClass())
```

There is such a compiler error:

```
type mismatch; found : Int required: ?{val getClass: ?} Note: primitive types are not implicitly 
 converted to AnyRef. You can safely force boxing by casting x.asInstanceOf[AnyRef].
```

I remember scala said "Everything is object in scala", why can't I invoke `num.getClass()`? And how to fix it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yep, everything is an object, but not necessary an instance of a java class/something with a getClass() method :)

Java primitive values (and Unit) are AnyVals in scala (instances of so called value classes), and - whenever it's possible - they are compiled to Java primitives at the end. When it's not possible boxing is done (similar to auto boxing in Java). But - as the error reports - boxing did not happen ("implicitly") in your case. Value classes don't have a getClass() method -> compilation error.

Java classes are AnyRefs (an instance of a reference class = a class instance in Java). getClass will work fine on them: AnyRef is practically the same as java.lang.Object -> it also has a getClass() method that you can call.

As the error recommends you can force the boxing, then getClass() will work on it:

```
num.asInstanceOf[AnyRef].getClass
```

will print

```
class java.lang.Integer
```

If you want to avoid boxing (e.g. you want to differentiate between primitive and boxed values) have a look at [HowTo get the class of _ :Any](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3139854/howto-get-the-class-of-any)

Answer (score 4):

The getClass method is only available for *reference classes* (i.e. scala.AnyRef). 123 is member of a *value class* (i.e. scala.Any) and thus does not have a getClass method.

See http://www.scala-lang.org/node/128 for the Scala object hierarchy. And www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/api/scala/AnyRef.html for AnyRef.

Answer (score 3):

Everything is object doesn't mean every object has a method getClass.
As the compiler says, 123.asInstanceOf[AnyRef].getClass would work.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I just learn scala 2 days, I know little about scala. I thought it had a "getClass()", because I thought every object should extend from java.lang.Object. And, do you mean, in scala, not every object extends from java.lang.Ojbect?